# What happened to the other Death Notes?

Tags: death-note

At the start of *Death Note* Ryuk says that there were other Death Notes falling to the human world in the past and Light

- Was the first to write so many names
- Was the first to think of a way to hide the Death Note

But what happened with these other Death Notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shinigamies probably collected them after the user died.
Ryuk mentioned that he will stick by lights side until he dies or the pages run out of space, I guess this was the case with the previous Death Note owners as well. It is also considered a great crime to lose your death note and return to shinigami world without it, as we see the third shinigami is seeking his note and can't get it back because it is in a humans possession.